# Sizing the subplot differently

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a huge snippet of code which is creating charts out of financial data. The following snippet is a simplified and shortened version that creates two subplots:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

y = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6])
z = np.array([2,2,2,2,2,2])
f, ax = plt.subplots(2, sharex = True)
ax[0].plot(y)
ax[0].plot(z)
ax[1].plot(y)
plt.show()
```

What is the easiest/more flexible way to make the second subplot (and any subsequent one, if required) of the same width of the first (since they share the axis x) but of half height?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`gridspec`](http://matplotlib.org/users/gridspec.html) for finer control over the sizing of the subplots. In addition to the example below, which shows 2:1 sizing by manually choosing the values, you can use  [relative sizing](http://matplotlib.org/users/gridspec.html#gridspec-with-varying-cell-sizes) as well.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

y = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6])
z = np.array([2,2,2,2,2,2])

ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((3,3),(0,0), colspan=3, rowspan=2)
ax2 = plt.subplot2grid((3,3),(2,0), colspan=3)

ax1.plot(y)
ax1.plot(z)
ax2.plot(y)
plt.show()
```

[image]